# No value accessor for form control with name 'control-name'

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to learn how to design a custom form control in Angular 5, by following one of the many tutorials I found. However, at the end of every tutorial, I'm stuck with the error in the title: No value accessor for form control with name 'control-name'. This is my code so far.

app-switch.html

```html
<div (click)="switch()" class="switch" [attr.title]="label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" [value]="value [attr.checked]="value" [attr.aria-label]="label">
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="On" data-off="Off"></span>
    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
</div>
```

app-switch.ts

```js
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-switch',
  templateUrl: 'app-switch.html'
})
export class AppSwitchComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() label = 'switch';
  @Input('value') _value = false;
  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  constructor() {}

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    if (value)
      this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  switch() {
    this.value = !this.value;
  }
}
```

app-switch.module.ts

```js
import {forwardRef, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateModule} from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {AppSwitchComponent} from "./app-switch";
import {NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppSwitchComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
  ],
  exports: [
    AppSwitchComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppSwitchComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppSwitchComponentModule {
}
```

And this is how I use the component:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <app-switch formControlName="mySwitch" [label]="'My Switch'"></app-switch>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this : <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <app-switch formControlName="mySwitch" [label]="'My Switch'" name="mySwitch"></app-switch>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: Tried, but I have the same problem.

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference, but the `value` attribute in your html is not closed properly. theres a missing quotation mark (`"`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put your NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR provider into the providers array of the AppSwitchComponent. Like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-switch',
    templateUrl: 'app-switch.html',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppSwitchComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
```